# Detect very early crashes

Tags: android

An app I published crashes on certain specific devices. I keep receiving messages from the users that just "can't open" the app. This of course lowers the rating on Google Play.

On Android Vitals there's no reference of these crashes, all crashes I receive are managed and happen after the app start, but if I filter for device model or Android version looking for those that tell me that the app didn't open, I find absolutely NOTHING.

I installed crashlytics, and I was astonished by the fact that I received completely different error communications, so Android Vitals seems just partial?
And anyway, still NOTHING about early crashes.

I tried to install the app on the official Samsung online emulator for some devices that are suspected to crash, and still... guess... NOTHING. So I can't even test it and I'm completely helpless.

How can I do to stop this bad app behaviour, that reduces the number of my happy users? I need a really reliable way to detect ALL crashes.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Crash Reporting Tool such as Firebase Crash Reporting. Everyone professional uses such tool

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

Comment: I'm already using crashlytics, as mentioned. It was acquired by google and it's going to be the main crashing reporting tool for Android.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use a crash reporting tool/framework, additionally you should be aware, that offline crashed might not get reported and if the user doesn't allow you to use the internet, there is no way around that, as far as I'm aware.

In the meantime you could try excluding the devices that you suspect to produce crashed while you are trying to fix it (if you care about the rating).

Comment: Yes, but I'm not even sure if the crashes are device-dependant or not, they might depend from ram, for example.... or from a conflict with another app. I've got absolutely no clue, I need something to undrerstand at least why it crashes...

Comment: Yes, but I'm not even sure if the crashes are device-dependant or not, they might depend from ram, for example.... or from a conflict with another app. I've got absolutely no clue, I need something to undrerstand at least why it crashes...

Comment: You might additionally want to test your app on real devices (firbase again).
In the end, that is the pain of using Android unfortunately. There are so many possible causes (did you check Versions or restrict them, did you exclude devices where APIs you use are not available etc.).